# Execute unix command in php

Tags: php

In php,I have to find whether a directory exist. IF it exists not a problem (I will display the hyperlink for that using the dirname)

Here is the sample in which I need help.
  dir_name is the directory name

```
$url = system(~'ls -d /home/myapps/rel/".$dir_name"');
        echo $url;(this does not work)
        if(preg_match("/No such/",$url)) {
                echo'Ther is no match'
        }
        else{
        }
```

In my code the if block is never executed.(it should execute if the directory does not exist) ;(

Comment: why you dont use php function like is_dir etc..

Comment: What's the `~` doing there? You also seem to have a wrong understanding of single and double quotes and variable interpolation.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use `is_dir()` ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Answer (score 4):

As others have told, `is_dir` is the right way to go.

I'll point out why your existing program does not work. This will be useful in cases when you want to run an external command and then parse its output.

- You have a unwanted `~` in your call
  to `system`.
- Variable interpolation does not
  happen in single quotes. So you need
  do something like:

  `system('ls -d /home/myapps/rel/'.$dir_name);` or

  `system("ls -d /home/myapps/rel/$dir_name");`
- Even with the above changes it does
  not work because if the dir does not
  exist, ls issues the `"....not
  found"` error on `stderr` and not on
  `stdout` and system just returns the
  last line of the `stdout`. To fix
  this we need to redirect `stderr` of
  the command to `stdout` as:

  `system("ls -d /home/myapps/rel/$dir_name 2>&1");`
- You also need to remember that
  `system` returns only the **last
  line** of the output. In the current
  case if works, but in some other
  cases if the external command being
  run spits many lines of error/output
  `system` will not work and you'll have
  to use `exec` which allows you to
  collect entire output lines in an
  array. Something like:

  `exec("ls -d /home/myapps/rel/$dir_name 2>&1",$output_arr);` 
    then you can search for your err string in the array `$output_arr`

So now you have the error message(if the dir does not exist) in `$url` and then check for the presence of string `"No such"`.

Some more problems with the approach:

- Some implementation of bash throw a
  different err message when you list
  for a non existing file. One I've
  seen is `/foo/bar not found` and this
  can cause your solution to break.
- Also if the value of `$dir_name`
  contains the string `No such` ( weird
  but possible) your solution will
  break.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
bool file_exists  ( string $filename  )
```

Returns true if file or directory exists. If you then need to find it out if its directory or file use `is_dir()`